# Assign value to object property and divide by length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there a way to assign a value to an object's property? I have a list of orders that are objects. They each have an items that are arrays that have the status in there. I want to get to the status and assign a number 1-3 (accepted, prepared, shipped) and divide by the length of the number of items to see how much of the order is completed.

obj orders has items that each contain a status.

Example of `orders` structure:

```
Array [0: Object { item: "shirt", status: "draft" }] Array [0: Object { item: "shirt, status: "failed" } 1: Object { item: "shirt" , status: "draft" }]
```

Code I have tried:

```
 for (var a = 0; a < list[i].orders.length; a++) {
     for (var b = 0; b < list[i].orders[b]['status']; b++);
         console.log(list[i].orders[b]['status']);           
 }
```

Here I have managed to console.log each items status in each order. I'm not sure how to assign a number to that status.

Comment: Would you mind providing part of your list object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set it the same way you would assign any value (with the `=` operator):

```js
var list = [
    {
        orders: [
            {
                item: "shirt",
                status: "draft"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        orders: [
            {
                item: "shirt",
                status: "failed"
            },
            {
                item: "shirt",
                status: "draft"
            }
        ]
    }
];
list.forEach(function(item) {
    item.orders.forEach(function(order) {
        switch (order.status) {
            case "draft":
                order.value = 1;
                break;
            case "failed":
                order.value = 2;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
```

I tried to recreate your object, let me know if the structure is slightly off.

EDIT:
Now that you have provided an example of your data structure, I have adjusted the code. Since you are assigning a value based on different statuses, a `switch` structure makes sense here, since no status has preference over any other status (whereas an if/else if/else structure would imply preference based on order).

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
Array [0: Object { item: "shirt", status: "draft" }]
Array [0: Object { item: "shirt, status: "failed" }
           1: Object { item: "shirt" , status: "draft" }]

So what I want to do is if they array has an object with the status draft give it a value of 1. if it has a status of failed give it a value of 2. Then divide by how many objects are in that array to get the address

Comment: @B8, you want to change the `status` property from `draft` to `1`?

Comment: Hello again. Quick question, how can I add the values of each order? I am not sure how to do that when they are in different arrays